# YouTrack 7.0 Proxy settings Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have gone through their documentation regarding [Proxy Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/2017.1/Proxy-Configuration.html?search=proxy) and the [Set JVM Options Manually](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/2017.1/Configure-JVM-Options.html) since I initially installed via MSI and still can't figure it out.

I created the `youtrack.jvmoptions` file in the `%programdata%\JetBrains\YouTrack\conf` directory and added the following settings [withTheProperValueOfCourse].

```
-http.proxyHost={servername}
-http.proxyPort=[portnumber]
-https.proxyHost=[servername]
-https.proxyPort=[portnumber]
```

[image: jvmoptions file entries]

When I try to start the service it fails, a look in the event log I find this

> The description for Event ID 404 from source youtrack (see below) cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
> The following information was included with the event:
> youtrack JetBrains JetService v1.1.730.777
> C:\YouTrack\launcher\bin\JetService.exe
> Service process exited without service stop request

I have even tried going via the System Properties and adding the settings without any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: youtrack proxy settings in System Properties]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While browsing StackOverflow JVM question and answers I came to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm); I noticed the user passing variables starting with

> -D

. Previously I had only used the `-` (dash) then the setting name and value. I updated the `%programdata%\JetBrains\YouTrack\conf\youtrack.jvmoptions` file to include the `-D` then the setting name and value. Restarted the server and when it came back online YouTrack was running with proxy settings taking effect.

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost =[servername]
-Dhttp.proxyPort =[portnumber]
-Dhttps.proxyHost=[servername]
-Dhttps.proxyPort=[portnumber]
```